# Model translation for Spree Commerce in Rails 5

Tags: bundler, ruby-on-rails-5, spree

Is it possible to have model translation for Spree 3.2 (through spree_globalize) in rails 5?
I followed the instructions but when I run bundle update, I get this error:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "spree_i18n":
  In Gemfile:
    spree_i18n

    spree_globalize was resolved to 3.1.0.beta, which depends on
      spree_i18n (~> 3.1.0.beta)
```

This is the relevant part of my gemfile

```
gem 'spree', '~> 3.2.0.rc1'
gem 'spree_auth_devise', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_gateway', '~> 3.2.0.beta'
gem 'spree_i18n', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n' 
gem 'spree_globalize', github: 'spree-contrib/spree_globalize'
```

Comment: I would avoid spree_globalize. Once I got it installed (I had the same issue as you) I got mountains of errors and issues. Issues logged in github never get answered any more either

Comment: You are probably right, I got a lot of errrors as well. Sadly that is the only gem I know that provides model translation, have you found other ways to achieve multilanguage on your site?

Comment: Not yet, I'll be spending tomorrow trying to figure out what's wrong with it, so if I have any luck I'll send you my fork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're encountering now is a common one with versioning of Spree add-ons. They tend to be pinned to one version of Spree, so when you upgrade you often end up having to fork the add-ons, modify the dependency requirements, test, maybe fix, then use it, upstream it. It's a bit of a hassle but it ends up working so that there's good support of add-ons compatible with every version of Spree.

In the world of Spree there's a consistent format to versioning. Spree and add-ons tend to have branches matching the version of Spree. For example, `3-1-stable` for Spree and all add-ons. Unless you require something from Spree 3.2, I recommend sticking with 3.1 since it's been out for months and most of the commonly-used add-ons have been updated and tested for it. Regardless of the version you go with, *make your add-ons use the same version as Spree!*. Life will be a lot easier that way. (Sidenote: I tend to hang at least one minor version back to wait for add-ons to be updated, bugs to be sussed-out before upgrading)

Here's what I do in my `Gemfile` to enforce consistency. You'll notice I'm request versions 3.1 of the add-ons *and* pointing to their 3-1-stable branches.

```
# Spree
spree_version = '3.1'
spree_branch = "#{spree_version.sub(/\./, '-')}-stable"

gem 'spree',                  "~> #{spree_version}", github: 'spree/spree', branch: spree_branch
gem 'spree_gateway',          "~> #{spree_version}", github: 'WebGents/spree_gateway', branch: "#{spree_branch}-quickpay-storage"
gem 'spree_auth_devise',      "~> #{spree_version}", branch: spree_branch
gem 'spree_static_content',   "~> #{spree_version}", github: 'spree-contrib/spree_static_content', branch: spree_branch
gem 'spree_sale_pricing',     "~> #{spree_version}", github: 'WebGents/spree-sale-pricing', branch: spree_branch
gem 'spree_i18n',             "~> #{spree_version}", github: 'spree-contrib/spree_i18n', branch: spree_branch
gem 'spree_variant_options',  "~> #{spree_version}", github: 'WebGents/spree_variant_options', branch: spree_branch
```

If you stick with version 3.1 you should find that the add-ons you want to use are all compatible and ready to go.